# Formatting escaped literal quotes in Ansible for PowerShell invoke-sqlcmd command

Tags: sql-server, xml, powershell, ansible

Reaching out to the community here. I am working on an Ansible script and have a requirement to insert some configuration data from a settings file into a Microsoft SQL Server DB. The settings are specified in XML.

**Settings JSON file example (ConfigData.json)**

```
{
   "ConfigDataXML": "<Settings xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><PathSettings=\"Windows\"></PathSettings></Settings>",
   "ConfigDescription": "OS File Config",
   "ConfigPermissions": "Readonly"
}
```

**Ansible DB Insert**

```
- name 'read config file into var'
  include_vars:
     file: ConfigData.json
     name: configData

- name 'add config to DB'
  win_shell: "invoke-sqlcmd -username \"{{db_user}}\" -password \"{{db_pass}}\" -Query \"INSERT INTO ConfigData (Data, ConfigId) VALUES ({{ configData.ConfigDataXML}},'{{ item.configId }}')\""
```

When the above is executed the INSERT fails as the PowerShell invoke-sqlcmd returns the error:

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'http'
```

This is due to the literal double quotes that have been escaped in the XML data. PowerShell requires that any double quotes must be escaped first by a backtick "`" therefore in order for the Config XML above to pass PowerShell syntax rules it would need backticks wherever an escaped double quote appears:

```
"ConfigDataXML": "<Settings xmlns:xsd=`\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`\" xmlns:xsi=`\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`\"><PathSettings=`\"Windows`\"></PathSettings></Settings>"
```

The problem: the JSON file is static as it is read in from another system therefore the can not be changed. The only choice is to have the Ansible script parse the XML string and add the backticks. I would like to know how to achieve this in Ansible please.

Comment: You can try the [`regex_replace` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters)

Comment: Any idea if the search term will need global pattern flag to match all? e.g. `/\\\"/g`

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server? Starting with v2016 there is JSON support. You could pass the string *as is*, use JSON to tread the content, cast this to XML and use XML's methods to do the rest...

Comment: @zeitounator changing the `{{ configData.ConfigDataXML }}` to include your regex_replace with backtick `{{ configData.ConfigDataXML | regex_replace('\"','\`\"') }}` works with my original SQL query

Comment: @mactwixs if this fixes your original problem, you should add this as an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted (unless there is already a better one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the XML does not contain any single quotes, this should work:

```
- name 'add config to DB'
  win_shell: |
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -username "{{db_user}}" -password "{{db_pass}}" -Query "
      INSERT INTO ConfigData (Data, ConfigId) 
      VALUES ('{{ configData.ConfigDataXML }}', '{{ item.configId }}')
    "
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_shell_module.html), the `|` introduces a multi-line shell command that removes the need for enclosing quotes and thus the need for any additional quote escaping.

---

If you expect single quotes in the XML, or just want to be on the safe side, you can use the `@"here-string"@` syntax like this (PowerShell requires a line break right after the opening `@"` and right before the closing `"@`, but between the two any combination of quotes and newlines is allowed without further escaping, which is very convenient for `{{placeholders}}` that could contain anything):

```
- name 'add config to DB'
  win_shell: |
    $xmlstring = @"
    {{ configData.ConfigDataXML }}
    "@
    $xmlstring = $xmlstring -replace "'","''"

    Invoke-Sqlcmd -username "{{db_user}}" -password "{{db_pass}}" -Query "
      INSERT INTO ConfigData (Data, ConfigId) 
      VALUES ('$xmlstring', '{{ item.configId }}')
    "
```

**Note/warning** None of this protects you against maliciously crafted values of `ConfigDataXML`. This might not be a likely scenario for your usage context, but "concatenating SQL from strings" is still unclean.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed idea. There are no single quotes in the XML. I tried the first part of your solution and it seems to give a slightly different error: `A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance><PathSettings=Windows></PathSettings></Settings>),'5481')` - so XML appears with no quotes now?

Comment: I have set single quotes around `{{ configData.ConfigDataXML }}`. Have you?

Comment: Yes confirm this is what I used `VALUES ('{{ configData.ConfigDataXML }}', '{{ item.configId }}')` + left .json file untouched with the escaped `\"`

Comment: The `\"` are a JSON requirement, they will go away when the JSON file is read, so that's not a concern. (Although the XML in your question is syntactically invalid, but I  guess that's just because you cut out a bit too much when shortening it before posting.)

Comment: @mactwixs Debug idea. Change `Invoke-Sqlcmd ...` into `Set-Content -Path "$env:TEMP\sqlquery.txt" -Value " the SQL query exactly as above"`. Look at the file this generates. Does it look like valid SQL to you? Tweak the `Set-Content` call until it looks right (and works when pasted into SSMS). After that, move back to `Invoke-Sqlcmd` with the updated query.

Comment: @mactwixs Any news on this?

Comment: @tomolak ran the here-string and PS errors with `No characters are allowed after a here-string header but before the end of the line` `FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedCharactersAfterHereStringHeader`

Comment: Try making lines break directly after the opening `@"` and before the closing `"@`.